# Badge for asking questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

Hello,

I've been(and still am) getting the best ever solutions to the questions I'm asking everyday at SO.The community is just more than great,I'm even advertising SO to my friends.

The amount of questions(137 and growing everyday) that I've asked in the past three months makes me a little ashamed so the idea of having a bronze(nothing useful) badge for asking over 100 or 1000 questions came to my head.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance to everyone! SO is great.

Comment: @John: since you've accepted Jon Skeet's answer (unless that an automatic feature of SO/SF/mSO <g>) am I right to assume that your feature request is withdrawn?  If so, this could be tagged to indicate that.

Comment: Actually he looked straight mad at his keyboard and it wrote the best ever answer,which made me accept it. If so many people wouldn't like to see that badge,why would I need to continue requesting that feature? @Joel,Thank you for the answer,could you tag my question - I don't know the tag.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/166155

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are already quite a lot of badges for asking good questions:

- Nice Question: question upvoted 10 times (bronze)
- Popular Question: question with 1,000 views (bronze)
- Notable Question: question with 2,500 views (silver)
- Favorite Question: question favorited by 25 users (silver)
- Good Question: question  upvoted 25 times (silver)
- Famous Question: question with 10,000 views (gold)
- Great Question: question upvoted 100 times (gold)
- Stellar Question: question favorited by 100 users (gold)

Were you wanting a badge simply for asking a large number of questions? I wouldn't personally support that - it would encourage people to ask lots of pointless questions just for the sake of it. Quality is more important than quantity IMO.

Answer (score 11):

I think getting answers is reward enough for asking questions.

Comment: +1 The OP suggested that, but it's great to emphasize that as our primary goal - good answers for good questions.

Answer (score 5):

**Votes for good questions are the proper reward.**  I am acutely aware of the effect of traffic - I'm active in Delphi areas, where views and votes are relatively low overall, whereas in the C# realm things are much busier and rep/badges accumulate quickly.

However, I think that's as it should be - we're not rewarded for effort, we're rewarded for results, and I know that Delphi has a relatively small user base right now (I think that's misguided, but it is what it is).

Comment: "I know that Delphi has a relatively small user base right now (I think that's misguided, but it is what it is)." It's not misguided, it's fairly accurate according to everyone's favorite flawed way of comparing language popularity: http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Comment: I meant to imply (and I really think I did) that the smallness of the user base is due to misguided decision-making (and that Delphi is actually a great tool, relative to other tools in the same space).  I did not mean to imply that my assessment of the smallness was misguided.  Thanks anyway for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

But there is no reward for just giving answers, either, unless they're upvoted or accepted.

If a question is upvoted or viewed enough there are badges for that (if it's badges you're after rather than answers to genuine questions?)

Surely, we're aiming to build a community where we can find answers to our questions but also help others from what we know. Both activities are rewarded (if others in the community find them helpful) and rewarding.

Comment: For a second I thought you were also after a badge for answering questions... I understand my error.

Comment: @Omar Kooheji: sorry if I was unclear. You are right, I wasn't proposing (more) badges for anything, but perhaps that's just because I know little about most of the popular SO topic areas, though I believe I know quite a bit about obscure programming areas that few others have an interest in: I suspect that's the lot of most systems programmers. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

> But there is no reward for just giving answers, either, unless they're upvoted or accepted.

But a badge given for answering questions is intriguing... Say, 100 answers upvoted at least once, for a Professor badge?  I think we should probably be rewarding providing answers above asking questions... It's *knowledge* we want to encourage, not the display of a lack of information.