# Give users a way to see their "Positive Question Record" score

Tags: feature-request, badges

I recently got awarded some new badges for different SE sites, however I was a bit surprised at which sites gave me which badges.

The badges are :

[image: Curious] 
*Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record.*

[image: Inquisitive] 
*Asked a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintained a positive question record.*

[image: Socratic] 
*Asked a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintained a positive question record.*

I can find out if I meet the "well-received question on X separate days" criteria with [this Data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/202534/asking-over-time-badges?bronze=5&silver=30&gold=100), so know the reason I did/didn't get a badge must be related to the "positive question record" criteria instead.

I found [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/158605) which defines the formula for determining your "positive question record" for the purpose of these badges as

> ```
> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5
> ```

But without knowing how many questions I've deleted over the years, or having a handy way to view them all at once, I have no idea what what my actual "positive question record" score is, and what I can do to improve it.

Is there a way to find out my "positive question record" score for a specific site?

---

Since the answer to this question seems to be *"You can't right now"*, I am going to change this to a feature-request per the [suggestion][3] of a moderator below.

Please implement a way for users to find out what their "positive question record" score is for a specific SE site, so that they can see how close they are to getting these badges and can work towards them.

Comment: Note that the actual implementation is more complicated than the suggested implementation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234959/167646

Comment: @Stijn: you misunderstood that reference. The 'good standing' requirement, plus the day count criteria is the complication. Jon refers to an earlier proposal in that post that did not include the separate days and good standing criteria.

Comment: Note that the SEDE queries cannot take deleted posts into account for the day count either. If you asked two questions on one day, one well-received the other deleted, the SEDE query will *incorrectly* count that day towards the badge

Comment: But to answer the question: *No*. No one but moderators can see the total deleted question count on your account. You yourself can only see questions deleted in the past 60 days. There is currently no way for you to find out the ratio.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah thanks for clearing that up, I must have confused the tabs I had open.

Comment: Given that the answer is basically, "You can't right now", maybe it makes sense to turn this into a feature-request?

Comment: @DavidFullerton Sure, its been updated. I honestly don't really care that much about badges though, and really only wanted to know if there was an existing way to see the score or not so I could find out why I did/didn't get the badges for some sites.

Comment: Did this change yet? 4 Years later, there does still not seem to be a way to find out your standing.

Comment: @BlkPengu To help get attention for this request, you can follow the tips at [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without)

Comment: @BlkPengu the short answer is "SE got more urgent things to do at the moment."

Comment: I was about to ask for the exact same thing. Just being told "not a positive question record" simply sucks.