# Does a closed question cancel out that day's valid questions?

Tags: support, asking-days-badges

I'm trying to understand how exactly the new Curious badge works.

Suppose I have "valid questions" on June 28, June 29th, June 30th, July 1, and today, July 2. That would earn me a Curious badge under the described rules for five days. But suppose I also had a closed question on July 2. Would I still be eligible for a Curious badge based on "valid questions?" Or would that cancel today's valid question?

**Edit"** "Valid question" is my term for "good question" because of the potential for confusion using "good question" in two different [contexts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234956/misleading-description-of-new-curious-badge)

Comment: Post your description suggestion as an answer there. Don't separate it into another question that's only partially related to it.

Comment: @animuson: I posted my answer on the other question as you suggested, and simultaneously, you edited my question. We make a good "tag team."

Comment: The new term is *well-received* instead of *good*.

Answer (score 7):

If you had a question closed on a given day, then that day does *not* count towards the badge, even if there were other questions on that day that qualified as 'well-received'.

As [Jon Ericson explains](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262301/badges-for-habitually-asking-good-questions):

> [D]ays with negatively-scored, closed, or deleted questions are not counted as good asking days even if you do ask a positively-scored question that day.