# Is there a query on SEDE that returns the questions eligible for the asking days badges?

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer, asking-days-badges

Is there any query on Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) that retrieves the questions which are eligible for the asking days badges (curious, inquisitive and socratic)? I could not find one*.

There is already [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206201/curious-inquisitive-socratic-badge-progress) nice query written by Bohemian, which returns how many questions are eligible, but it does not return which ones they are.

I read in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234966/does-a-closed-question-cancel-out-that-days-valid-questions) thread that if one question is deleted, closed or is negatively-scored the day it is asked, even though there were other well-received questions that day, they will not count towards the goal.

This is the motivation for my question, i.e., to visualize among the positively-scored questions, which ones are good to go. If such a query does not exist yet, it would be nice if someone could write it up. Tks.

<sub>*I don't know how to write one either.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

[Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) wrote the [definitive query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202534/asking-over-time-badges) for this already. This gives you a) the *number* of qualifying *days*, and what badges you'd have earned with those day counts.

However, take into account that *deleted* questions are not included in the data set so the query can only give you an approximation.

Comment: Tks. Not sure if I followed your answer. For example: currently I have 4 questions eligible, but which ones? Can I retrieve that information in Jon's query?

Comment: @AndreSilva: But it is the *days on which you asked* that matter for the badge. You can play with the subqueries to get more info, but you'd need to extract the dates on which you are eligible, then map that back to the questions you asked on those days.

Comment: @AndreSilva: Really, this isn't about the individual questions, but *all questions for that day*.

Comment: No problem. This is nice information already. I was just curious to know if there was a way to see which threads lead towards that number of days. For example, if one user has 32 positively-scored questions asked in separate days and a record which passes the criteria, but let's suppose in three days out of these 32 he/she also asked questions which were deleted. Then, this user would need one more question to qualify for the Inquisitive. The query would provide the correct information (29), but maybe the user would be confused because the 32 questions. Thanks for replying, anyway.

Comment: @AndreSilva: the query would then count too many days as qualifying. Only the user and moderators can see what was deleted, for the user it is limited to questions deleted in the past 60 days. That makes it easier for the user to check on what days they had deleted questions and discount the corresponding number of days.