# Remove the periods from the new badges' descriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Once again the new badges - Curious, Inquisitive and Socratic.

Their descriptions on the [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) have periods at the end:
[image: screenshot 1]

The problem is that when I click on the badge to see who has earned it, there is one more period added:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Maybe they're going for a Charles Schultz vibe.

Comment: One thing is for sure, they provide tons of rep to many users by reporting related bugs! :-)

Comment: I noticed this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was fixed when the description was [slightly reworded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234956/misleading-description-of-new-curious-badge/234959#234959).