# The term "good question" in some badges' description is unclear

Tags: bug, badges, help-center, badge-description, asking-days-badges

The badges, *curious, inquisitive* and *socratic* are described as:

> Ask a **good question** on *N* separate days, and maintain a positive question record

However the term *good question* is not explained. From my account at least it doesn't refer to the *good question* badge:

> Question score of 25 or more

I think these badges' description should be clarified, probably to something like:

> Ask a question on **N** separate days with a score of one or more, and maintain a positive question record

Comment: originally it was spelled as "good..." but later changed to ["well-received question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234959/165773). Probably it was changed back again later