# Do deleted questions count for the total questions when calculating positive question record?

Tags: support, badges, asking-days-badges

For [the new badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) positive question record is calculated thusly:

```
(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5
```

We can see that deleted questions are subtracted too, but are they included in `total questions`? In other words: Does `total questions` mean every single question that the user ever asked no matter what its fate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes

This is why you can't calculate the question record with [public data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202517/asking-record), which does not include deleted questions.

Comment: Also, if I ask questions that are not closed/deleted and have 0 upvotes aren't those questions going to increase my positive question record while they aren't really "positive"?

Comment: Yes. They count in both the numerator and the denominator. And yes, it is possible to ask nothing but 0 score questions and still have a "positive record" of asking. But you need upvotes in order to get the badges.