# badge progress tracker bugged

Tags: support, badges, tracking

This cannot be right, can it?  It seems that the tracking is not synchronized with the actual badge awarding mechanism.  Perhaps there is a bug in the awarding and I should have this badge already, or I am ineligible for it for a reason that the progress tracker is unaware of.

[image]

Comment: @Martin I would not disagree with that closure.  Ironically it will make it harder for me to earn this badge without a change to the criteria.

Comment: Weirdly, after double-checking, the question isn't even *technically* a duplicate, but that question itself answers yours. I wonder what the closing policies for that are...

Comment: @MartinBüttner If another question is the same, it's a dupe. If another *question* actually "answers" this one, then it's a *super dupe*...

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291497/349538

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks weird, ya, but click on the badge itself. You should have the [positive record too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges), while you don't :)

[image]

Comment: Hm... of the questions I can still see I believe I easily have a positive record.  Perhaps there are more deleted questions than I remember?  Is there some way to check that?

Comment: You can only check [*recently* deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/158428) (<60 days old)

Comment: Ah, I think I have a possible explanation.  Are \[duplicate\] questions counted as negative?  I think I have quite a few of those.  However I was not aware that these were considered "bad behavior" as I understood them to be useful pointers in the search engine.

Comment: @Mr.W yes, they do. The algorithm [at the link I pointed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) includes closed questions, and dupes are closed questions too.