# Can we change the way the badge progress for the asking days badges is displayed?

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

Currently, the badge progress for the Curious, Inquisitive and Socratic badges looks like this:

[image]

When I don't have a positive question record, it only says "need a positive question record", without saying anything about how close I am to having a positive question record. So I therefore have no idea about how close I am to earning this badge, and I can't check either because of [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341878/4284627).

I would therefore suggest changing the design so that instead of just saying "need a positive question record", it actually says how close I am to having a positive question record, using the `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions` formula. Doing so would also solve [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234963/349538) which is asking for there to be a way to see the question record (note that this is not a duplicate since that question is asking that there should be a way to see the question record and I'm asking that the badge progress should be displayed differently).

I also think that the badge progress without clicking on the button should show the question record instead of the days asked when the user has asked a well-received question on more days than the badge requires (otherwise still show the days asked, for example if a user has asked a well-received question on four separate days the Curious badge progress should continue showing 4/5). This is because I think that it looks weird seeing a 12/5 progress ([and I'm not the only one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287516/349538)), and it would make more sense seeing for example 0.4/0.5. Note that a similar feature is already implemented for the Elecorate badge (see screenshots of [my badge progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv4Kn.png) and [Jon Skeet's badge progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpLhB.png)).

It would also be useful to add a link explaining what a positive question record is in case a user doesn't know what it means (which is fairly common, I myself misunderstood completely what it meant when I was a new user). I therefore think that the words "positive question record" should be turned into a link to a Meta post explaining what a positive question record is, for example [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290546/349538).

In case the above wasn't really clear, I've made a picture in Paint illustrating my feature request:

[image]

Note that the picture is just supposed to illustrate the main ideas, so it's totally OK to me if the moderators decide to design it a little bit differently.

Comment: A progress bar doesn't make sense for something that isn't progress. As well, there's a very awkward lower bound to that number, as it can go negative since a question which is all three downvoted, closed, and deleted would count against you three times. I don't know how expensive of a query is required to display that number, but if it does get displayed at some point, it definitely would not be as a progress bar.

Comment: @animuson [The Electorate badge displays a progress bar for the percentage of votes on questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpLhB.png) and that's not really progress either. And if the question record is below 0, the progress bar could be empty in the same way as the one for the amount of well-received questions is full when the user has asked more well-received questions than the badge requires.