# The tick mark in the Curious badge info is confusing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, badge-progress

In the Curious badge, there are 2 conditions.

1. Ask a well received question on 5 separate days.
2. Maintain a positive question record.

Anyway even if I didn't have a positive question record, it shows a tick mark in the left side of the message **Need positive question record**.

[image]

#### This is another one where I **have** positive question record and this one is correct.

[image]

So, the first one should be an **X**.

---

<sup>*I didn't remember exactly but I think previously it was like that and got bugged in the recent profile page update*</sup>

Comment: It used to be correct: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291497/can-we-change-the-way-the-badge-progress-for-the-asking-days-badges-is-displayed (see screenshot there.)

Comment: hmmm my guess is correct. in the first image in the link you provided, it is an **X** in a round. so bugged in recent update.

Comment: tick probably better to replace with thumbs up mark: 

Comment: @gnat nah, it's ugly. At least in Chrome. Black and really not clear what it is.

Answer (score 4):

## [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

Looks like a developer silently fixed this issue.

The **X** is returned for label *need positive question record*.

Now it looks perfect

In sites which I need positive question record.

[image]

In sites where I have positive question record

[image]

Comment: Happened in the last few hours, cheers!!

Comment: Sorry, I had poked a designer about this based on a support ticket because I didn't want to reply telling them they didn't qualify while there was a checkmark indicating they did. I didn't realize there was a Meta question about it.

Comment: As an aside, what happened is we changed it to directly insert an SVG image there, whereas before it was an icon class and the background position changed based on whether it had a completed class. This was overlooked and it ended up with always a checkmark SVG with a completed class that wouldn't do anything. It now inserts the correct SVG based on completion state.

Comment: I have the same problem here but I have a positive record on those questions and I still not getting the badge