# Why doesn't SO give me the badge I deserve?

Tags: support, badges

Please take a look at this screen-shot:

[image]

So, as you see, I'm obviously deserve to get **inquisitive** badge ..! I'm really confused, Why SO doesn't give me that? Until now, 15 days past since the day that I am worthy to getting that.

Well, What is the reason that I don't have it now? And when SO will give me that?

Comment: Do you have a positive question record? (If you click that badge you will see two bars)

Comment: Truly a longshot, but I might have heard in the past that having a question with negative score acts against the count for that badge. You have 3 questions with negative score, so maybe it means you'll get the badge when having 33 "well received" questions

Comment: @ShadowWizard well obviously the badge progress should take the *actual badge criteria* into account so that when it reaches 100%, it's actually at 100%. Or did SE hire the [Windows progress bar guy](https://xkcd.com/612/) to do this?

Comment: @Mat lol, true, but maybe the count is dummy, and not based on the actual formula. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When badges require multiple criteria, the graph on the profile page only shows progress on one of them - the one that needs a certain number of things, typically. In your case you have enough days with well received questions, but you may not have the overall "positive question record".

The progress bar isn't some sort of binding commitment, it's a visual aid so you can see how you're doing. Look at this from my profile on Travel:

[image]

My bar shows I have 838 of the 600 votes I need to cast. But I don't have the badge, because I didn't cast 25% of my votes on questions (oops.) I can't stomp my feet and demand to be given the badge I deserve because the bar has gone all the way across.

You can check whether you have a positive question record by clicking on the badge dropdown. Here's mine for Socratic here on Meta:

[image]

I have a green tick next to "positive question record." If you do too, then you have a badge bug. If you don't, then you know why you didn't get the badge yet. If you don't, then you need this formula from [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5

Comment: My question is as good as your answer ..! But why your answer got more votes? `:-(` Well enjoy it ...!

Comment: Your question may have contained an error. You originally tagged it `bug`, and you stated several times you should have the badge. You haven't clarified (in a comment or edit) whether you have a positive question record or not. This missing information could be why some people are not upvoting your question.