# Track duplicate badge progress (second gold badge, etc)

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress, asking-days-badges

Just got the [Socratic badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic) on StackOverflow and, since *it can be awarded multiple times*, wanted to start tracking progress to the next one, but, the badge is not shown in Available badges to track anymore:

[image]

Is it possible to track already awarded badges that can be awarded multiple times?

Comment: Hmm, when the progress tracker was built, that badge could only be awarded once, so it's not currently capable of counting past the first award. Would require some code changes to the way it functions in order to count further awards.

Comment: @animuson Anytime soon we expect it ?

Comment: @animuson You should opensource that one on nuget, `JeffsBoolCounter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to see how many questions you still need to ask before being awarded your second Socratic badge, you only need count those questions that have scored at least +1. Visit your profile page, set your questions page to votes, and at a glance you'll see your position. There's only one snag, if by chance you posted two or more questions on the same day, they won't count.

> Ask a well-received question **on 100 separate days**, and maintain a positive question record. This badge can be awarded multiple times

For example, on EL&U I have asked a total of 147 questions, five questions have scored 0 or lower. This leaves me with 142 question, ergo I need to ask another 58 questions before I can win my second Socratic badge. Which won't be happening any time soon.

I don't know if this answered your question, it's Christmas evening, it's late where I am, I've been cooking and doing the washing up all day and maybe my brain is playing up, but this seems a relatively simple solution.

Comment: That's not the solution to his problem.  He knows what it's awarded for, he's asking about fixing this bug/feature.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ I thought it might have been too easy, but the answer possibly explains why it's not a necessary feature, and Python Master's answer points out you cannot track multiple badges. I saw that his answer had attracted zero votes, so I thought maybe the OP wanted to know *how*.

Comment: Not anymore, I have a score of 2 :)

Comment: @PythonMaster well, I do hope the OP selects your answer :) I mean I *really* hope he does.

Comment: Thanks for the "This is a Fine" hat :)

Comment: The day also doesn't count if you've posted a negatively-received question on the same day, regardless of whether you've posted positively-received questions on that day.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog citation? Because if I ask three questions on one day  and  two of them receive upvotes but one doesn't, then of the two  remaining questions one of them should still count.

Comment: By "negative" I mean downvoted, closed, or deleted. See the post regarding the exact criteria for each badge for a citation.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog and if one question gets a downvote but the other two get at least one upvote if not more, the negative question cancels both of them? I don't think so. As I understand it, the rule implies that you can post 10 positive questions a day, but only one of them counts toward the badge.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, the one negatively-received question will cancel out that entire day. Per the [list of badge criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/377214), "any day that has at least one Positive question *and* also has no Negative, Closed, or Deleted questions counts as a 'qualifying day' which increments the counter."

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog then it's a silly calculation. Two positives vs one negative leaves you with one positive. It's math(s). It doesn't bother me tho', I rarely post two questions on the same day.

Answer (score 13):

This is due to the fact that the progress tracker only tracks badges you have never earned previously. For example, I have the ["Custodian"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/184/custodian) badge, which can be awarded multiple times, but shows as already earned and thus cannot be tracked:

[image]

Clicking "Custodian" does nothing and of course has a grey background to signify that it's not a choice. This will also apply to *all badges that can be awarded multiple times*. Only a code fix by a Stack Exchange developer can allow anyone to track a badge they have already earned and can be awarded multiple times:

> animuson: Hmm, when the progress tracker was built, that badge could only be awarded once, so it's not currently capable of counting past the first award. Would require some code changes to the way it functions in order to count further awards.

Comment: This is also not an answer. This is a feature request. The obvious response to this is "change this user-interface, it's not doing what people want."

Answer (score 4):

The [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) does not have (enough) information about deleted posts, which [do play a role](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) in the badge determination. Most people qualifying for multiple Socratic badges won't have that much deleted questions to begin with; if you know you have one or more which influence the determination, just subtract that number from the # of days produced by [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/919952/socratic-badge-progress).

This is my progress on Meta ...

[image]

... last Sunday (SEDE refreshes once a week on Sunday morning). It's a [little bit outdated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic?userid=295232) right now.

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
-- Note: SEDE doesn't include (enough) information about deleted posts
-- to take the full criteria described here:
-- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/295232
-- into account.

CREATE TABLE #questions (CreationDate DATETIME, Score INT, Closed BIT);

INSERT INTO #questions
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreationDate), 0), Score,
  CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM Posts  
  WHERE OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##
    AND PostTypeId = 1

SELECT 'Question record score (needs to be >= 0.5)',
  CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #questions) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE
  ROUND(((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #questions)
       - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #questions WHERE Score < 0)
       - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #questions WHERE Closed = 1))
  / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #questions) AS FLOAT), 2)
  END

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Days with well-received questions', 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p.CreationDate))
  FROM #questions AS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #questions AS n ON p.CreationDate = n.CreationDate
                                 AND n.Score < 0
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #questions AS c ON p.CreationDate = c.CreationDate
                                 AND c.Closed = 1
  WHERE p.Score > 0
    AND p.Closed = 0
    AND n.CreationDate IS NULL
    AND c.CreationDate IS NULL)
```

(Community Wiki questions do count towards this badge, I've checked this on my Meta Stack Overflow account.)