# Replace raw links with the current question title in bounty notice

Tags: feature-request, bounties, hyperlinks, bounty-remarks

I just started a bounty on [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271984/339911) with the notice that contains a raw link to the MSE question and the link remains raw.

> [image: bounty notice]

It would be well to replace raw links with the question title, like it [done for post content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49433/339911), especially since [editing a bounty notice is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357152/339911).