# How do migrated questions count for the Asking Days badges' positive question record requirement?

Tags: support, questions, badges, migration, asking-days-badges

The Asking Days badge series (curious/inquisitive/socratic) are only awarded if the user has a 'positive question record', which the [initial post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) describes as the requirement that

```
(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5
```

However, this is a bit ambiguous on how it deals with migrated questions. Are they counted as closed? As closed and deleted? Or are they simply eliminated from the count altogether?

Comment: Migrated _is_ closed.

Comment: I would assume that they would be counted as closed until the stub is auto-deleted, then as closed and deleted. They would also be included in negative questions if downvoted before migration, though the downvotes are cleared on the migrated copy.

Comment: ... so there are multiple reasonable interpretations, hence the need for clarification on how this is actually implemented.