# Why isn't my question record positive?

Tags: bug, badges

[image]

According to that info box, the only thing I don't a positive question record. However, the math says I should. [According to my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/307833/mego?tab=questions):

- I have asked **8** questions
- Of those, **3** are closed
- **0** have been deleted
- **0** have a negative score

According to the [formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges), I have a question record score of:

```
(8 - 0 - 3 - 0)/8 = 0.625
```

That's well above the `0.5` threshold. So why don't I have a positive question record (and therefore the Curious badge)?

Comment: Are you totally sure that you haven't deleted any questions? They wouldn't show up in your profile.

Comment: @HDE226868 I'm relatively sure, but if there's no way to check, that's horrible design.

Comment: I see three deleted questions, one of which has negative score.

Comment: @Oded Man it would be great if I could see that so I wouldn't be so confused.

Comment: @Mego  You can view your own deleted questions.  There is a link at the bottom of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/307833/mego?tab=questions) page to view recently deleted questions.

Comment: @Ramhound That only shows recently deleted questions. The page is blank for me.

Comment: How long ago did you have questions deleted?  I have no idea which community you have deleted questions on, you should go to the community with the deleted questions, to view them.

Comment: @Ramhound I have no idea. Hence the confusion.

Comment: @Ramhound This is here on Meta.SE

Comment: @Mego The system has its own rationality, it tolerates much more "deviance" as most internet sites, but to understand what you can do and what you can't, is not trivial. You have to understand, where are the mines on this battlefield, you won't ever reach earthshaking results, but you can reach a tolerable compromise with it, if you understand it. There are also many side-effects what you can use for a specific purpose (for example, data SE has a minimal info about deleted questions, it can help you to find your deleted posts).