# New badge suggestion: "Wise helper"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, badge-request

I was looking at high rep user profile on the SE site I use a lot and I found one that had around **30k rep... and has asked no questions**! I know that user, he always answers with many details, plus I know he's one who shares a lot of his knowledge on other websites with high quality web articles.

So I went on to other high rep users and discovered they also asked very few questions (for example a user with **60k for 8 questions** only!).

I felt **those users deserved some kind of reward** for being **great answerers**.

The rule would be something with a high rep based regarding to their asked questions rate. I don't know this website enough to make up a good rule, but I felt it might be something like that.

Why **Wise**?  Because they have a lot of knowledge (they don't need to ask questions) while they share it a lot ("**helper**").

(I looked at other badge suggestions and I didn't find anything looking like this one - I may have missed one...)

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to MSE! Generally we want badge suggestions to explain what action we are trying to encourage the badge incentivizes. What benefit to a site is having someone who never  (or rarely) asks questions? As a note, with the higher reward for answers, it's much easier to earn reputation for answers and answering questions is (arguably) more difficult than writing good ones.

Comment: @Catija I understand, yes... It's the downside of my suggestion, but I feel it can't encourage people not to ask question, really. It's more a reward for high rep users that don't need really to ask question and are helping a lot.

Comment: Maybe you should be more clear about what you think should trigger the badge, then? You introduce the question with a story about a user who has asked no questions (I fit that description on most sites because I never come up with good questions)... Is this a badge that is triggered by having low/no questions asked with high reputation or someone getting X rep from answers alone?

Comment: Hum... yes, you're right. It's not as easy as i first thought. I admit i don't really know how we could reward those users by putting up a good rule. I'll try to think on it. They give a lot of their time to the site and i was looking for a way to thnaks them for this time they spend answering to people.

Comment: Relevant: [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259) where Jon Ericson points out that the habit of some active users never asking questions is not really that helpful to the sites. Prolific answerers would be even better contributors if they also asked questions.

Comment: see [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)

Comment: Thanks..seems I'm not alone :) I thought when I had put the answer as accepted it would stop... but it doesn 't !

Comment: "Would this help for the question to stop collecting downvotes? Unlikely, and here is why - readers do not perceive "accepted" checkmark as part of the question itself (which is not entirely wrong by the way since asker can unaccept any time they want). To reader, the question still reads as promoting the wrong way, and same reasons for downvotes as explained above still apply..."

Comment: This is awful. I was just trying to help with an idea and I feel like stupid now. I guess that's the first and last question I'll ever post here...

Comment: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44189/165773)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I'll probably come back to participate in Meta when I'm more familiar with the whole thing. Getting used to the local SE site is sufficient enough for me. "Heavily Consider Not Suggesting Anything If You Are New" seems a good advice...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We implement badges to encourage specific behavior here, not just to reward users for random interesting things.

In this situation, the user is already encouraged in a *lot* of ways to create quality answers for the site. Tying an extra badge to creating quality answers under the additional criteria that they hadn't asked anything does not encourage any further positive behavior that isn't already encouraged. In fact, it would probably end up discouraging some users from asking so they can work towards this answers-only badge, which is certainly not something we want.

The fact that they participate with answers only is fine - we value their knowledge greatly whether they're asking or answering the questions. But only ever providing answers isn't anything that warrants a badge.

Comment: I understand. As @Catija pointed out, it would not be easy to set anyway :)