# In what time should I expect to get certain amount of reputation in SO?

Tags: discussion

Considering that I have some intermediate level knowledge in my domain, In what time should I expect to reach 5000 reputation in SO (keeping in mind that I am a regular user) ? Since, last few months I have managed to earn ~600 reputation in SO. Am I doing well ?

I would also like to know personal experiences of highly reputed users as how they started their journey.

Comment: To add a joke: 6-8 something :-D

Comment: At some point you realize that *reputation* is meaningless. I answer to help someone, so should you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how much ***effort*** and ***time*** you want to ***invest*** ... And if you are willing to do a sufficient effort, then just choose your battles. I.e look for some selected tags that fit your area of expertise, and then start posting high quality answers (and add more self answered questions you can think of). ***Easy, no?***

BTW, it's how I, some years ago, started my journey on Drupal.SE (concentrating on tags such as `Rules`). And soon, in 2016, [I reached my goal I had set for myself when I joined Drupal.SE](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/220/year/drupal/2016-01-02).

PS: suggesting edits to tags and/or posts that get approved, allows you to earn another 1.000 rep points ... So if you can effort the time to submit like 500 suggested edits (in a couple of days/weeks), you already have 1.000 points.

Answer (score 5):

> Considering that I have some intermediate level knowledge in my domain, In what time should I expect to reach 5000 reputation in SO (keeping in mind that I am a regular user) ?

There aren't any solid statistics about this, and what should be an average time.

> Since, last few months I have managed to earn ~600 reputation in SO. Am I doing well ?

Also it's hard to tell you something about *Am I doing well ?*. Earning ~600 reputation within a few month isn't that bad, but also heavily depends on the particular field you are working on.

In conclusion your question is primarily *opinion based*, and we can't give a clear answer.

---

Besides my statements made above, there are many positive actions you can do at these sites (not only SO), for which you won't earn reputation, but maybe badges.

It's a kind of game, and you shouldn't be focussed at reputation gain.

Focus about helping to improve the overall sites quality in the view of creating a FAQ repository that is helpful for anyone.

IIRC that is still the goal of what we're all doing here.

Answer (score 4):

> Since, last few months I have managed to earn ~600 reputation in SO. Am I doing well ?

You're doing great!  Thank you for your contribution.

<sup>(NB. I may have been looking at wholesome memes today.)</sup>

Personally, I wouldn't worry so much about the rep [they're just Internet points], and instead set your own goals and enjoy the ride.  I prefer to aim for the [Socratic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic): it's hard to get 100 upvoted questions at a site without learning a significant amount along the way.

You gain [privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) with rep, but many only help you do janitorial work more efficiently.  Getting 3000 to be able to [cast close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) is nice.

Comment: _"but many only help you do janitorial work more efficiently."_ But that's quite essential though. I am just mentioning.

Comment: "But that's quite essential though."  I'm a bit confused as to what "that" refers to.  Janitorial work is essential (and I don't intend to suggest otherwise), but I feel doing it more efficiently is not urgent for inexperienced users.

Comment: Re. the Socratic badge, there's mention of a "well-received question". Is there a clear definition of "well-received"?

Comment: Here it is: [A well-received question is one that's open, not deleted, and has a score > 0.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)