# What does "well-received" mean in the description of the "Sunrise" hat?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

The description of the "Sunrise" hat mentions:

> Ask a question that's well-received by the community on a site you haven't used before.

But what does "well-received" mean?

Upvoted? or not-closed?

For me it isn't clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/773001), a well received question is one that

- is open *(not closed)*
- is not deleted
- has a score > 0