# Sunrise hat description is a bit ambiguous

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

The description for the sunrise hat says "Write a well-received first question." However, if you click about, it says "Ask a question that's well-received by the community on a site you haven't used before." So which one is it: can I get the hat on a site where I haven't asked any questions before (but have otherwise used the site), or can I only get for sites which I haven't used at all? If it is the former, what does using the site constitute? Does voting or commenting count as using?

Comment: Related: [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)

Answer (score 4):

All it means is that it has to be your first question on the site, and it must be a well-received one. Other actions do not matter.

Comment: Have you tested this, or or have any other confirmation for this?

Comment: @nobody I shall let you know soon :)